# After installing Tablib library using pip some methods are not available

Tags: python, pip

According to the [Tablib documentation](http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/latest/api/#dataset-object) the 0.9.11 version should have a method `get_col(index)` on `Dataset`

However when I use pip to install Tablib this and other methods are not available.

E.g. `core.py` in [tablib-0.9.11.tar.gz](http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/t/tablib/tablib-0.9.11.tar.gz#md5=72ebb27dd1d2476d358dfc75fc90dc8f) from pypi does not have a `get_col()` method while [`core.py` from Github](https://github.com/kennethreitz/tablib/blob/develop/tablib/core.py) (develop branch) does, event hough both files are `__version__ = '0.9.11'`

I'm new to the Python environment so I would appreciate it if someone could point out what I'm missing.

**EDIT:**

I just saw that [`core.py` on the Github Master branch](https://github.com/kennethreitz/tablib/blob/master/tablib/core.py) doesn't have the `get_cols()` method.
So, I guess my new questions are:

- I like the convenience of pip; is there anyway that I can get the "latest" version of Tablib 0.9.11 using pip?
- If not, what would the easiest way be to install Tablib without pip since [I'm also having trouble](https://github.com/kennethreitz/tablib/issues/52) with the latest Github version?

Versions:

- Python 2.7.1
- Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: I won't make this an answer because I'm not sure, but I'm 85%+ confident that you're not missing anything, and it's nothing more than the fact that the documentation was generated from some trunk version post-0.9.11.  Often people don't increment the version number in code until a tagged release, so that doesn't surprise me.

Comment: Thanks DSM, that does seem to make sense especially since the Develop branch has the code but Master hasn't, as I pointed out in the edit.

Comment: I've opened an issue at https://github.com/kennethreitz/tablib/issues/82 so let's see if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Github will give you a compressed version of any branch with the right URL.  Pip can use that URL to directly install.

The URL structure is

```
https://github.com/{username}/{projectname}/archive/{branchname}.{file_extention}
```

To install the newest master

```
pip install https://github.com/kennethreitz/tablib/archive/master.tar.gz
```

To install the newest develop

```
pip install https://github.com/kennethreitz/tablib/archive/develop.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks James! Can I also put the full URL in the pip requirements.txt file?